# Update XML node keeps adding value instead of uppdating

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I cant seem to get this query right. What I'm trying to achieve is:

Update the value inside my text node.

But the problem is that instead of updating the value it keeps adding the value to the element.

Say I $_POST 'Hello' to the value. It adds value. But later I want to change the value `'Hello'` to '`God Bye'` instead of modify the node to `'Hello God Bye'`.

I have tried I'm using PHP DOM. But can't seem to get it with SimpleXML either.

Any suggestions ?

This is what I have for now:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = TRUE;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE; 
$xml->load('../stickers.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id="559428"]/text');
$result->item(0)->nodeValue .= 'Hello';

echo $xml->saveXML();
$xml->save('../stickers.xml');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$result->item(0)->nodeValue .= 'Hello';
```

into

```
$result->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Hello';
```

The dot there is concatenating the strings.

Comment: OMG!! I have been struggling for DAYS with this.. Thank you so much!! I love u!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.=` which is meant for adding onto strings. Replace it with `=`.